# Widget fixed sized icon Android

Tags: android, widget

My application has a widget I added, I would like this widget to be a fixed size image on the device without the user option to resize it, is it possible? 
P.S : I want my widget to be 2x2 without the user option to resize.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the soulution,its very simple
on the provider xml change:

```
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
```

to

```
android:resizeMode="none"
```